# How to get textbox value in codebehind and textbox generated dynamically by using loop?ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, gridview, textbox

How can i get `textbox` value in code behind and `textbox` generated bynamically by using loop.I want to insert values in gridview using these `textboxes'.Here is my`gridview` image [image: LINK]

ASPX:

```
<form id="form" runat="server">
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="true" 
    onrowdatabound="GridView1_RowDataBound">
</asp:GridView>
<asp:Button ID="Button3" runat="server" OnClick="save" Text="Save" />
<asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" OnClick="show" Text="Button" />
</form>
</asp:Content>
```

ASPX.CS

```
 public void show(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string s = Session["num"].ToString();
    int num = Int32.Parse(s);

    for (int i =0; i <num; i++)
    {
        TextBox _text = new TextBox();
        _text.Visible = true;
         _text.ID = i.ToString();
         this.form.Controls.Add(_text);
   }

}

public void save(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   string s = Session["num"].ToString();
    int num = Int32.Parse(s);
    DataTable t = (DataTable)Session["tab"];
    DataRow row1 = t.NewRow();
    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
    {
        foreach (Control f in form.Controls)
        {
            if (f is TextBox)
            {
                TextBox txt = (TextBox)f;
                string str = txt.Text;
                row1["Name"] = str;
                row1["address"] = str;
                row1["num"] = str;
                t.Rows.Add(row1);
            }

        }
    }
    GridView1.DataSource = t;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

When i click on `show` button then 3 `textboxes` generated(show) and i want when i insert values in textboxex and press `Save` button then value show in `gridview` in `Name`,`address`,`num`

Answer (score 0):

You need to address a number of issues

ASPX

Note the addition of a PlaceHolder Control.  This is used to make managing Dynamic controls easier.

```
<form>
  <asp:PlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolder1" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
  <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="true"></asp:GridView>
  <asp:Button ID="Button3" runat="server" OnClick="save" Text="Save" />
  <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" OnClick="show" Text="Button" />
</form>
```

---

CodeBehind:

Here is my assumption of what is/needs to be going on in your Page_Load event

1. You create a DataTable *once* and store it in Session.
2. You gridview datasource must be set on every postback.  But only re-bound when you do a save
3. You must recreate your dynamic fields EVERY time (`CreateTbx()`), but since you want them only initially displayed via button control you need a mechanism to determine when that button has been hit, hence Session["shown"] boolean flag and is initialized once.

   ```
   protected void Page_Load ( object sender, EventArgs e )
   {
       if ( !Page.IsPostBack )
       {
           Session[ "num" ] = 3;
           DataTable tab =   new DataTable();
           Session[ "tab" ] = tab;
           tab.Columns.Add( "Name" );
           tab.Columns.Add( "address" );
           tab.Columns.Add( "num" );

           Session[ "shown" ] = false;
       }

       GridView1.DataSource = ( DataTable ) Session[ "tab" ];
       CreateTbx();
   }
   ```

---

4. Here the Show button has been clicked and the dynamic fields are created via call to CreateTbx()

   ```
   public void show ( object sender, EventArgs e )
   {
       Session[ "shown" ] = true;
       CreateTbx();
   }
   ```

---

5. Here I made the ID more inline with conventional naming standards.

   ```
   private void CreateTbx ()
   {
       if ( ( bool ) Session[ "shown" ] )
       {
           string s = Session[ "num" ].ToString();
           int num = Int32.Parse( s );

           for ( int i =0; i < num; i++ )
           {
               TextBox _text = new TextBox();
               _text.Visible = true;
               _text.ID = string.Format( "TbxInput{0}", i );
               PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add( _text );
           }
       }
   }
   ```

---

Import changes here versus your original code:

6. I'm using the PlaceHolder Count versus `Session["num"]`.  `Session["num"]` is needed for creation, not processing.
7. Using a direct reference to the Session table rather than assignment to a local variable.
8. you should not loop through individual columns via for loop and assign column values buy column name.
9. Add a row to a table only once.  you are looping through columns, not rows
10. Note that we only need to rebind and not reassign the GridView Datasource

    ```
    public void save ( object sender, EventArgs e )
    {
        DataRow row = (( DataTable ) Session[ "tab" ]).NewRow();

        for ( int i = 0; i < PlaceHolder1.Controls.Count; i++ )
        {
            string tbxid = string.Format( "TbxInput{0}", i );
            TextBox txt = ( TextBox ) PlaceHolder1.FindControl( tbxid );
            row[ i ] = txt.Text;
        }

        ( ( DataTable ) Session[ "tab" ] ).Rows.Add( row );

        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
    ```

Hope this helps